# Custom Content List View in Sensenet

Tags: sensenet

I created Audit CTD, AuditFinding CTD as child content which both extend Folder CTD. I also have AuditList where I put Audits.

I wanted to create a custom List View to show only AuditFindings when Audit is open for browsing. However, I cannot get Sensenet to display AuditFinding fields in the View Composition section, it always displays Audit CTD fields. Upon removing and re-adding markup template, the system automatically generates default view fields.

Comment: Hi, are the Audit and AuditFinding content types related, or both simply inherit from Folder? What do you want to store in your list - only Audits, or AuditFindings too? Because you will see fields on the ViewComposition UI of content types that are allowed there (see Allowed Child Types field on the content list).

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. Let me make a quick clarification: Audit and AuditFinding are related, both inherit from Folder, but AuditFinding should be sort of list item for Audit. What I am after is the functionality identical to ExpenseClaim demo workspace, specifically ExpenseClaimItemView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To view fields on the View Composition panel, you'll have to make sure that:

1. the content type (in this case *AuditFinding*) is **allowed in that list** (otherwise SenseNet wouldn't know that you want to display those fields in your list view)
2. the fields you want to display have to be **visible** at least in one mode (New, Edit or Browse) - see the [ctd field configuration section](http://wiki.sensenet.com/Content_Type_Definition#Field_definition) for setting this.

Comment: In Expense Claim demo workspace (expenseclaimworkspace), Expense Claims (Custom List) has ExpenseClaim and File as allowed CTD. When you open properties of ExpenseClaimItemView.ascx under Views, the list of fields for ExpenceClaimItem CTD.

Comment: Ok, I think now I get what you need. Strange: I see only DisplayName, Description, Name and Sum fields on the list view edit page (on our daily demo site) - the last one is a field of the main ExpenseClaim type. So I do not see the child item types fields. The only connection is that in the ExpenseClaim CTD (so not on the actual list, but in the content type definition) ExpenseClaimItem is an allowed child type.

Comment: There is custom View Frame defined at /Root/System/SystemPlugins/ListView/ExpenseClaimItemViewFrame.ascx. I will follow that lead. Thanks.